# Android 11 - Folders structure of hundreds of Categorized applications with their unique manually selected folders Backup

Tags: android-11, nexus, folders

I made folders of applications according to their categories on my Android 11 Tablet, I have hundreds of Applications due to my needs and work, for this reason they need to be categorized, each folder has its own name and its individually selected icon (from Nexus Icon packs).

The whole process of creations and assigning is very boring and time wasting. in order to save time on each factory reset operation I need to make backups of all those folder structures and their manually selected icons.  Can anyone help on how to backup all of those things with their folder structure and icons.

Comment: It sems like you are talking about the launcher and the app icons/folders it shows. Have you tried to use a launcher that supports exporting/importing it's configuration like [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) (AFAIR import/export requires the paid "prime" extension).